# Golang Sending messages to multiple clients via websocket gorilla

Tags: go, websocket

I'm trying to create a "broadcast" format where connected clients will receive the same messages at a time. However, at the moment it turns out that the messages come in turn. For example, client 1 receives 1,3,5,7,9, and client 2 receives 2,4,6,8,10. How can this be corrected?

server:

```
conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Print("Error during connection upgradation:", err)
    return
}
defer conn.Close()

// The event loop
for {
    list, err := handler.processor.TakeList()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    if err != nil {
        WrapError(w, err)
    }
    err = conn.WriteJSON(list)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error during message writing:", err)
        break
    }
}
```

Client1 :

```
var interrupt chan os.Signal

func main() {
interrupt = make(chan os.Signal) 

signal.Notify(interrupt, os.Interrupt) 

socketUrl := "ws://localhost:8080" + "/socket"
c, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(socketUrl, nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Error connecting to Websocket Server:", err)
}
defer c.Close()
done := make(chan struct{})
go func() {
    defer close(done)
    for {
        _, message, err := c.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("read:", err)
            return
        }
        log.Printf("recv: %s", message)
    }
}()

ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
defer ticker.Stop()

for {
    select {
    case <-done:
        return
    case t := <-ticker.C:
        err := c.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte(t.String()))
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("write:", err)
            return
        }
    case <-interrupt:
        log.Println("interrupt")

        err := c.WriteMessage(websocket.CloseMessage, websocket.FormatCloseMessage(websocket.CloseNormalClosure, ""))
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("write close:", err)
            return
        }
        select {
        case <-done:
        case <-time.After(time.Second):
        }
        return
    }
}
}
```

Client2 has similar code

Comment: There's some code missing from the server side. Does `TakeList()` read from a shared channel? If you have multiple readers reading from one channel, only one reader will get each message. You would need to use multiple channels, and broadcast the message to all channels.

Comment: Start with the [Gorilla chat example](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/chat#chat-example).  If TakeList does not block, then call TakeList from the hub goroutine loop.  Convert the result to []byte and send to clients as in the example.  If TakeList does block, then spin up another goroutine to call TakeList in a loop. Send the result to the hub’s broadcast channel.